# IE developer tools - network - Timeline of network event

Tags: internet-explorer

I am measuring the network traffic time of my application with IE developer tools "Network". May I know how to get the actual timeline as below image?

I am trying the countdown the actual timeline without elapsed time that mean my completion time of my testing.

I tried to export the HAR file but no any value to indicate the actual timeline.

Any idea? Thanks a lot

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoJXf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE browser version are you using? From your description, it seems that you want to check the detailed timeline of the network events. I have exported the HAR file using IE11 browser, then, we can find the detailed timeline from the "timings" node, screenshot as below:

[image]

[Note] The entity also contains a "time" node, it logs the time to load the server response (not calculated for cached responses)

More detail information about F12 developer Network Tools, please check these articles:

[Analyzing your webpage's network traffic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255004(v=vs.85))

[Network Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/network)

Comment: but i checked this node is not indicated to the actual time that just a elapsed time per each request.

Comment: which version of IE browser version are you using? I'm using the IE 11.116.18362.0 version. Can you capture a screenshot about request entity, which node it contains?

Comment: IE11 11.1087.16299.0

Comment: Lv I checked the Analyzing your webpage's network traffic but i have not the detail view in my ie11.

Comment: Yes, at present, it seems that the IE browser Network tools not contains the summary and detail view options, but if we hover the timeline, or click the request the detailed information will display in the right slider, then, we could click the "Timings" tab to check the details timeline. Screenshot like this. [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc6jA.png).

Comment: but cannot indicate actual timeline the in the whole recording.

Comment: e.g my recording is around 10s but the elapsed time  should be taken 5s that represent the response time. i hope to get the value with 10s in somewhere.

Comment: can you find the "time" and "timings" node in the HAR file request entities? Please check the picture in my reply, the "Time" will time to load the server response (not calculated for cached responses), and the "timings" provides a timeline of network events involved in the loading of the selected resource.